# Encoding Extreme - 1

Tags: number-sequence, letters

*You wake up. You are on a very small room. There is a paper on the floor, and you don't know how to exit. Can you decipher the note to escape?*

This is the note:

```
9%110111111220222222330445330550567443660770554070000605000000000
```

Good luck trying to escape.

Hint #1:

> Numbers(in the example, '9') before the % are the length of the whole phrase you're trying to decipher.

Hint #2:

> You need to put all the numbers on a list. Put (Length of the phrase) horizontally, then go down. Like this:
> 110111111 Then, down.
>
>  220222222
> Repeat that (lenth of the code)/(Lenth of the phrase) On the example, it's 63/9 (We don't count the 9%) If you do 63/9, you get 7. So you need to repeat that 7 times.

Hint #3:

> After getting table (On hint 2), think about a LED calculator.
>  It's formed of vars, not?
>  Think that every var is a number.
>  Like this:

... `1`

`2|-----|3`

`4 -----`

`5|-----|6`

...    `7`

> Now get every column, and get the numbers of each. Now you can figure out what to do with those numbers! ;)

Comment: I've been trying to solve this one, but I don't think I made much progress. Could you give us a hint as to what exactly we're trying to find? Is it a word? Two words? A phrase? A sentence? A map? Something else?

Comment: What does "It's formed of vars" mean?

Comment: We need clarification on your third hint. Your diagram makes no sense, and "It's formed of vars" and "every var is a number" is rather vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given all OP's hints, this is almost directly spelled out for us already, but the answer is (intended to be)

> NO ESCAPE

This is found by

> Reading the % as a modulo operator of sorts, and dividing up the string of digits to the right of it into chunks of the length of the digit to the left of it (i.e., nine-character chunks, in rows), then treating the numbers in the columns as the cells in an LCD number display, as described in OP's hints above

See:

> `1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1`
>  `2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2`
>  `3 3 0 4 4 5 3 3 0`
>  `5 5 0 5 6 7 4 4 3`
>  `6 6 0 7 7 0 5 5 4`
>  `0 7 0 0 0 0 6 0 5`
>  `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`
>
>  Treating the numbers as the cells as outlined in OP's hints, with 1 indicating the top H bar, 2 indicating the top left V bar, 3 indicating the top right V bar, 4 indicating the center H bar, 5 the bottom left V bar, 6 the bottom right V bar, and 7 the bottom H bar, and treating each *column* as a character, you get LCD-styled letters spelling out NO ESCAPP, as follows:
>  `.  _   _       _   _   _   _   _   _`
>  `. | | | |     |_  |_  |   |_| |_| |_|`
>  `. | | |_|     |_   _| |_  | | |   |`
>
>  The last column should read (down) `1 2 4 5 7 0 0` (E) instead of `1 2 0 3 4 5 0` (P).
>
>  Read on for more details.
>  Seven-segment display:
>  `.  _`
>  `. |_|`
>  `. |_|`
>
>  We can label the segments as follows:
>  `.  1`
>  `. 2 3`
>  `.  4`
>  `. 5 6`
>  `.  7`
>
>  Generally we can represent a combination as a binary number, indicating which segments are lit up. E.g. 1111011 would be all segments but #5 lit up, giving us a "9":
>  `.  _`
>  `. |_|`
>  `.  _|`
>
>  OP used a slightly different notation, where instead of indicating for each segment whether it is lit up or not (binary), he just gives us the numbers of the lit up segments, and pads with 0s if not all the segments are lit up. To indicate a "9" (1111011), it would be 1234670. A "0" (1110110) would be 1235600.
>
>  Reading the numbers column by column, we get:
>  1235600, 1235670, 0000000, 1245700, 1246700, 1257000, 1234560, 1234500, 1203450. The last number deviates from how the others are displayed (0 in the middle, not padded at the end), so we presume it's just equivalent to 1234500.
>
>  Placing the seven-segment display of these combinations next to each other, we get "NO ESCAPP":
>  `.  _   _       _   _   _   _   _   _`
>  `. | | | |     |_  |_  |   |_| |_| |_|`
>  `. | | |_|     |_   _| |_  | | |   |`

Comment: Honestly, OP's hints were horrible. +1 just for being able to understand what they were trying to say.

Comment: @TheAnathema I think my first tipoff was when I realized they meant "LCD" when they said "LED", and that helped me figure out that "vars" was probably supposed to be "bars", and *then* I made sense of the diagram

Comment: What would have made it more recognizable would have been to referring to it as a 7-segment display

Comment: You got it right! Awesome!

Comment: Oh wow, nice. I somehow missed the fact that the numbers were ascending in columns - that would have helped a lot in arriving at the solution, in the absence of hints.